# TypeERROR after yarn upgrade (ReactJS project)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, typeerror, yarnpkg

I ran the command yarn upgrade and then I got this error next time I did yarn start, and I have no idea why? Hoping someone can tell me whats going on here? No idea what to do to solve it. Tried googling it, without much luck as to what is wrong.

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
at validateString (internal/validators.js:113:11)
at Object.join (path.js:375:7)
at noopServiceWorkerMiddleware (C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\react-dev-utils\noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js:14:26)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at launchEditorMiddleware (C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\react-dev-utils\errorOverlayMiddleware.js:20:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at handleWebpackInternalMiddleware (C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\react-dev-utils\evalSourceMapMiddleware.js:42:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\perni\Projects\prime\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Try undoing the upgrade and only upgrade one dependency at a time.

Comment: Mass upgrades are a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Yeah...I've learned that now - whoops.

Comment: I tried rolling back to a git commit that  I know works, but I still get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `yarn cache list` to print out your cached packages, then you can compare with the version in your `package.json` to make sure they match.
If you still get errors, run `yarn cache clean` to clear your entire cache and run `yarn install` to repopulate them.

Comment: You're a hero. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the node-modules and reinstall  with you new version

Comment: I went back to a git commit from earlier and still have the issue, this seems weird. I know 100% it worked on the last commit.

Comment: delete your lock files and reinstall,

Comment: My yarn.lock? How do I regenerate it?

Comment: just reinstall it should automatically  regenerate

Comment: Alright, I did that and I still get the same error. :-(